# Java initialization block placement in code

Tags: java, constructor, initialization

Can the initialization block be placed anywhere in the class file? I mean 1 initialization block before constructor and another between 2 methods.

Comment: Yes, as long as it's not inside a method but inside the `class` directive.

Comment: They can be placed where you want but they are all invoked before the constructor

Comment: 'Can it be placed there?' and 'Should it be placed there?' are two different questions

Comment: thanks. got confused while reading the OCA/OCP Java 7 by kathy sierra. Page 140, exam watch section.

Comment: Those exams (as well as the preparation books) are really nasty. Instead of focusing on important things like the api they bring up irritating things like this (or one of my "favorite" questions: "What's the result of this threading code?" - answer: "It doesn't compile because there's a semicolon missing.") ;)